# Django go live with Nginx from server on local network

Tags: django, nginx

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) to test going live with a django website.

I don't have a DigitalOcean droplet but a local machine I have that eventually could be used as a server. Therefore, in the steps where I had to put the domain name I used the local machine IP address (it's the same IP address I use to login with ssh).

All steps were ok and I have a response from whitin the local machine, i.e., if I open a browser in the local machine and with the IP address, the Django app runs ok.

However, the same does not happen if I open it from an external computer. I'm not sure if it was suppose to work like that. Is it? If not what extra steps do I need to do to go public?

Comment: I would advise against trying to do this. There are several steps involved so it’s probably too broad a question for Stack Overflow. You need a public IP address if you want external users to be able to acess the server. If you don’t have a static IP, you would need to configure dynamic dns. You might also need to configure port forwarding on your router so that requests are passed on to your local server. You could look at services like ngrok but they are usually used for debugging not production. If you can afford it, renting a vps for a few dollars a month would be much simpler.

Comment: Ok, thanks for summing up all the steps.